# Does jQuery support reading JSON from X-JSON HTTP headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http

Is jQuery able to read JSON data from X-JSON HTTP headers returned by the server? I've been searching through the jQuery docs, but all the examples I can find use JSON returned in the request body rather than the headers.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to use a header to transport data?

Comment: @gahooa: Prototype encourages it, because it's "easier" than multipart responses: http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2009/04/07/ruby-developers-ignore-security-risks-claim-x-json-header-lsquonothing-seriousrsquo.aspx and http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/94728 shed light on the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to call the [`getResponseHeader` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader-method) of the `XMLHttpRequest` object, and do the JSON de-serialization manually:

```
function getHeaderJSON(xhr) {
  var json;
  try { json = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Json') }
  catch(e) {}

  if (json) {
    var data = eval('(' + json + ')'); // or JSON.parse or whatever you like
    return data
  }
}
```

Note that the `try`/`catch` is for some versions of Firefox where if the header is not present an error is thrown. I can't remember which version(s) were affected.

You have a couple ways to get a reference to the `XMLHttpRequest` object in jQuery:

1. hook into the **`complete`** callback of the ajax request, as opposed to the expected `success` callback (jQuery is kind of inconsistent wrt to what args are passed in what order to what callback function or global ajax trigger):

   ```
   $.ajax({
     // ...
     complete: function(xhr) {
       var data = getHeaderJSON(xhr);
       // do with data as you wish
     }
   })
   ```
2. Alternatively you can save a reference to the `XMLHttpRequest` object returned to you from calls to `.ajax`/`.get`/`.post` etc, via a [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures). This allows you to use it inside whatever callback you choose (ie `success` or `complete`, or `error` for that matter):

   ```
   var xhr = $.ajax({
     // ...
     success: function() {
       var data = getHeaderJSON(xhr); // access xhr var via closure
       // do with data as you wish
     }
   });
   ```

So to answer your title directly: no, jQUery obviously doesn't support this OOTB.

Comment: I didn't know what OOTB means. I looked up: "Out of the box". A variant is "Out of the blue".

Answer (score 1):

as of 1.4 jQuery's success: callback receives XMLHttpRequest -- (data,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest). So you don't have to use the complete: callback anymore, as laid out above.

Wish I could reply to the previous answer instead of adding a new answer.